# Maven Liquibase what is the purpose of @update annotation

Tags: maven, liquibase

What is the difference between this two command line? in other words what is the purpose of the `@update` annotation since the first command line runs correctly for me, unlike the second one:

```
mvn -Dparamname=value liquibase:update@update
```

and

```
mvn -Dparamname=value liquibase:update
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>update</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/ddl/release/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
                        <url>${app.liquibase.url}</url>
                        <username>${app.data.username}</username>
                        <password>${app.data.password}</password>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>NONE</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
...
```

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml? The syntax with the `@update` seems very out of the ordinary.

Comment: @SteveDonie i have made the edit you asked, thanks.

Comment: So what you have done is explicitly made it so that the update goal is not bound to any of the maven lifecycle phases. The first invocation is saying "run the plugin named liquibase, with the update goal, and the execution with id update", so that works. The second invocation is saying "run the plugin named liquibase with the update goal" but because that goal is explicitly *not* bound to a phase, it can't run it. The maven documentation goes into more detail on this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: @SteveDonie thank you for the explanation it's clear to me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is explicitly made it so that the update goal is not bound to any of the maven lifecycle phases. The first invocation is saying "run the plugin named liquibase, with the update goal, and the execution with id update", so that works. The second invocation is saying "run the plugin named liquibase with the update goal" but because that goal is explicitly not bound to a phase, it can't run it. The maven documentation goes into more detail on this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html